# Overlay two heatmaps in seaborn (one being frames around cells in the other) from a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have this simple problem: I have two data frames, one df_signal with columns (row, column, intensity), the other df_det with (row, column, detected), where "intensity" is a float and "detected" is binary 1 or 0.

I'd like to overlay the df_det data frame over the df_signal frame in a heatmap, where cells that were detected have a frame around them.

I'm also happy to use a plotting library other than seaborn, if this makes it easier.

Comment: What have you tried so far that didn't work?  It'd be a lot easier to help if you provide a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with an explanation of where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Saeborn is built on matplotlib, if you go to the matplotlib level you can manipulate everything how you want it. But that's all I can say unless you provide code and examples.

Comment: FWIW, consecutive calls to `seaborn.heatmap()` will plot the next heatmap on top of the previous one, treating cells containing `np.nan` as transparent.

Answer (score 9):

I would not recommend to use seaborn here, since that makes it more difficult to get the correct scaling for data with units (as seaborn uses categorical values on the axes). Instead one may use a matplotlib `imshow` plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate data
x = np.linspace(-3,3, num=11)
y = np.linspace(2,8, num=11)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
signal = np.random.rand(len(x)*len(y))
det = np.random.poisson(lam=0.5,size=len(x)*len(y))
det[det>1] = 1

df_signal = pd.DataFrame({"y":Y.flatten(), "x":X.flatten(), "intensity":signal})
df_det = pd.DataFrame({"y":Y.flatten(), "x":X.flatten(), "det":det})

# prepare Dataframes
df = df_signal.pivot(index="y", columns="x")
dfmark = df_det[df_det["det"]>0]

#plotting
fig, ax=plt.subplots()

x = df_signal["x"].unique()
y = df_signal["y"].unique()
ext = [x.min()-np.diff(x)[0]/2.,x.max()+np.diff(x)[0]/2., 
       y.min()-np.diff(y)[0]/2.,y.max()+np.diff(y)[0]/2. ]
ax.imshow(df, extent=ext)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_yticks(y)

ax.scatter(dfmark["x"], dfmark["y"], marker="s", s=100, c="crimson")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Instead of the scatter, you can create a frame by using rectangles:

```
dx = np.diff(x)[0]; dy = np.diff(y)[0]
for (xi,yi), in zip(dfmark[["x","y"]].values):
    rec = plt.Rectangle((xi-dx/2.,yi-dy/2.),dx,dy, fill=False, hatch="\\",
                        edgecolor="crimson", lw=2 )
    ax.add_artist(rec)
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, thanks! Unfortunately I'm not allowed to upvote your answer because stackoverflow has this strange policy not allowing newcomers anything.

Comment: There is good reason for not counting votes from new accounts. However, you may still upvote and this vote would be counted once you have enough reputation points. But you may decide to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer, if it solves your question. If it doesn't, you may further clarify your needs and/or wait for a different answer.